# unmark selected row in DT shiny R

Tags: shiny, dt

I have a question. It is possible to unmark selected row in DT in shiny code? 
To get selected row I use

```
s <- input$tableName_rows_selected
```

And I would like to unmark this row. I tried to find some update function without success. I also tried

```
input$tableName_rows_selected <- NULL
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in this app: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-proxy/
there is also a code